# How to build a custom Windows OS AMI for AWS EKS?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, amazon-eks

I need to use a specific custom Windows AMI as the base image to build an AMI to be used by EKS worker nodes. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you tried the https://aws.amazon.com/image-builder/ service?

Comment: No. The AWS Image Builder creates EC2 AMI. A Windows AMI for EKS requires some special sauce and I hope someone knows what's required and how to do it. AWS does not seem to provide documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions in the page [Creating custom Amazon EKS optimized Windows AMIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-custom-ami-windows.html)

You can create a custom Windows AMI for a Kubernetes node by either

1. Using an Amazon EKS optimized Windows AMI as a base image
2. Using the Amazon-managed build component